How do I cut these curves in geo nodes?
I've created vines that grow up the side of a castle wall.

I want to simulate them being cut down.
I could create an entirely new geo node set up where there are two segments and one falls away, then cut it together. But I'm wondering if there are any inventive ideas anyone has to simulate this in the current set up?
Bonus objectives:
-The stems curling up like they would in real life.
-Falling vine debris.
Here is my current node set up:

